# TFS On Prem Maintenance Mode

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to do some maintenance on my on premise TFS instance.

Is there a way to show take it offline while i do changes on the application configuration and backup the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **TFSServiceControl** command to stop or start all of the services and application pools used by Azure DevOps Server or Team Foundation Server (TFS). For example, you use this command when backing up or restoring databases.

```
TFSServiceControl [quiesce|unquiesce]
```

This is mentioned in the document, please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsservicecontrol-cmd?view=azure-devops) for details.